# Freemarker null exception even though checking for it first

Tags: java, freemarker

I have the following code:

```
<#if !(task.dueDate??)><span class="datetime">Date: ${task.dueDate?string.medium_short!""}</span></#if>
```

It is supposed to protect from the situation in which dueDate is null but I still get the exception: Expression task.dueDate is undefined

Any ideas on how to solve?

Thanks,

Assaf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Freemarker reference says](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_test) that the missing value operator (??) returns true if the value is **not** missing. Because you need that you should not use the negation (!) in the if clause.